# Godel's proof of incompleteness and the real line?

Tags: formal-languages, incompleteness

As far as I understand, Godel's incompleteness theorem uniquely numbers the possible statements that can be built and then applies the diagonalization argument of Cantor. But any system that can represent the real line will by default have a non countable list of true statements, right? It seems that a much more powerful form of incompleteness would be if you could omit a whole category of statements and their implications and still prove incompleteness. I am not yet familiar with the complete vocabulary of mathematical logic, but is my intuition right?

Comment: "But any system that can represent the real line will by default have a non countable list of true statements, right?" Why ? the number of statements depends on the language: with only e.g. two individual constants ($0$ and $1$) and the usual syntax of FOL, the number of formuals will be countable (formulas are *finite* strings of symbols).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The set of statements $ d/dx(sin(kx)=kcos(kx) for k \in R $ is an uncountable set of true statements in PA, I guess

Comment: "will by default have a non countable list of true statements": you assume that any real number can be explicitly associated to a statement. This is wrong. statements have a finite lengths hence are countable. You can't extend $x=a$ for all real $a$.

Comment: @user2277550 The differential statement you gave Mauro cannot be formalized in PA.

Comment: @user2277550: no this is a single statement. (Otherwise you wouldn't have been able to write it down.)

Comment: NO; using: $k \in \mathbb R$ to generate statements means that you have in your language a "name" for each $k \in \mathbb R$, which is not so straightforward.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus But you can get real numbers out of PA right?

Comment: @user2277550: even so, you can't enumerate them.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Of course they can't be enumerated. I don't see how that affects anything.

Comment: @user2277550: that's the crux of the problem. The statements are enumerable.

Comment: Note, incidentally, that in the language of ordered fields, the first-order theory of $\mathbb{R}$ is *complete* and *decidable*; we call it the theory of "real closed fields". This doesn't contradict Godel's incompleteness theorem -- instead the incompleteness theorem simply allows us to conclude that we can't reproduce the theory of peano arithmetic.

Comment: @Hurkyl But you need PA to get to $\mathbb R$, right?

Comment: Ok, so how do you get real numbers out of PA ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Well I am not very sure, but integers+ closed in division --> rationals  and rationals + cauchy ---> irrationals. Or something like that, I guess.

Comment: How do you define cauchy sequences in PA ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I don't see why it shouldn't. A countable set of rationals can give you an irrational right? I mentioned Cauchy cause that's how a book I once studied seemed to get it.

Comment: How do you encode a countable sequence in PA ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67660/discussion-between-user2277550-and-rene-schipperus).

Comment: I guess I should have asked this question after 2 more semesters.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: PA is capable of describing logic which is capable of describing Turing machines, which can be used to encode functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$. The problem is that most such functions cannot be given by Turing machine.